# Missing kanji with platex/dvipdf

Tags: fonts, cjk, dvipdf, platex

I'm trying to compile a document with platex, but certain kanji do not show up at all in the resulting pdf.

```
\documentclass{jsarticle}

% unless I have this line, I get ascii mojibake for some reason
\usepackage[jis2004]{otf}

\begin{document}
こんにちは！

桔梗の模様の鞄があるけど、その鞄の字は見えない。

「虔む」も同じだ。他の字はオーケーなのに。おっかしいなー。

じゃあ、スタック交換に訊いてみよう。
\end{document}
```

Compile using:

```
platex hoge.tex && dvipdf hoge.dvi
```

End result:

[image: wrong rendering]

Expected:

[image: correct rendering]

Terminal output, as requested:

```
$ dvips hoge -o
This is dvips(k) 5.994 Copyright 2014 Radical Eye Software (www.radicaleye.com)
' TeX output 2015.10.01:1542' -> hoge.ps
</usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/dvips/base/tex.pro>
</usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/dvips/base/texps.pro>. 
</usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmr10.pfb>[1] 
$ gs -dSAFER -dNOPAUSE -dBATCH -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -sOutputFile=hoge.pdf hoge.ps
GPL Ghostscript 9.06 (2012-08-08)
Copyright (C) 2012 Artifex Software, Inc.  All rights reserved.
This software comes with NO WARRANTY: see the file PUBLIC for details.
Can't find (or can't open) font file /usr/share/ghostscript/9.06/Resource/Font/HiraMinProN-W3.
Can't find (or can't open) font file HiraMinProN-W3.
Querying operating system for font files...
Loading HiraMinProN-W3 font from /usr/share/fonts/truetype/apple/ヒラギノ明朝 ProN W3.otf... 2932428 1603756 23747972 13461862 1 done.
Loading HiraMinProN-W3 font failed.
Can't find (or can't open) font file /usr/share/ghostscript/9.06/Resource/Font/HiraMinProN-W3.
Can't find (or can't open) font file HiraMinProN-W3.
Didn't find this font on the system!
Substituting font Courier for HiraMinProN-W3.
Loading NimbusMonL-Regu font from /usr/share/fonts/type1/gsfonts/n022003l.pfb... 3069668 1728253 23747972 13469851 1 done.
```

Comment: I know the answer: use `dvipdfmx` and not `dvipdf`, and can create a very short answer. If someone can elaborate on that, you're free to answer and steal the reputation.

Comment: With `dvipdf` I get just junk in Courier font, which seems to mean that it can't find all the needed fonts.

Comment: Please, do `dvips hoge -o` followed by `gs -dSAFER -dNOPAUSE -dBATCH -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -sOutputFile=hoge.pdf hoge.ps` and then add the terminal output.

Comment: Well, I believe that the log you reported fully answers your question.

Comment: @egreg Do you mean that ghostscript can't load the font? But the fonts are all there. Also, how come the other glyphs are successfully rendered?

Answer (score 3):

The font ipaexm.ttf, which is in TeX Live, has all glyphs
for your example. Try

```
platex hoge
dvipdfmx -f otf-ipaex.map hoge
```

If you have Hiragino fonts, try

```
dvipdfmx -f otf-hiragino.map hoge
```

or

```
dvipdfmx -f otf-hiragino-pron.map hoge
```

If you want to use dvips + Ghostscript,
try to add the following 6 lines to hoge.ps:

```
--- hoge.ps.orig    Thu Oct 01 23:46:40 2015
+++ hoge.ps Thu Oct 01 23:47:31 2015
@@ -6,6 +6,12 @@
 %%PageOrder: Ascend
 %%BoundingBox: 0 0 596 842
 %%DocumentFonts: HiraMinProN-W3-H HiraMinProN-W3-Identity-H CMR10
+%%BeginFont: HiraMinProN-W3-H
+/HiraMinProN-W3-H
+/H /CMap findresource
+[/HiraMinProN-W3 /CIDFont findresource]
+composefont pop
+%%EndFont
 %%DocumentPaperSizes: a4
 %%EndComments
 %DVIPSWebPage: (www.radicaleye.com)
```

Further, copy your font (symlink may be ok)

```
/usr/share/fonts/truetype/apple/ヒラギノ明朝 ProN W3.otf
```

into

```
/usr/share/ghostscript/9.06/Resource/Font/
```

with the PostScript name

```
HiraMinProN-W3
```

Comment: Indeed, but since I have the Hiragino fonts, I'd like to use them. They, too, have all the glyphs.

Comment: @oals -- See added examples.